# Slow WIFI in Windows8, Fast in Windows 7 PC and wired connection in Win8

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking

I was having Win 7 OS in my dell lattitude E6410 model laptop and it was working fine with my ATT Uverse internet connection.In Sep, i upgraded to Windows 8 and that too worked fine. Last week i changed my providr to comcast xfinity and i noticed that i am getting very slow internet when i am connected to the WIFI network. Connecting to the ethernet is giving me the proper speed i am supposed to get as per the plan.

I tried with a Windows7 PC and IPad and both gave me good speed. The problem is only with the Win 8 PC !

Here is a comparison image (from speedtest.net)
[image]
Anyone know what am i missing in my Win8 box ? I went to device manager and tried "Update driver" option on the network driver(broadcom) and it told me that my driver is up to date. Also i do not have any antivirus blocking my internet. Anyone know how to fix this problem ?

EDIT : Adding the WIFI Settings details from gateway.
[image]

When i change the channel selection to manual. I have only 1,6 an 11 as enabled. Tried all these and no improvement in win8 pc speed.

Comment: I sincerely doubt the difference in speed is OS-related. Are the three devices in the same location when running the test? Did Comcast provide you with a different wireless router, or are you using the same one you have always used?

Comment: All devices in same device. comcast sait it is a problem with my win8 pc as win7 and ipad works fine

Comment: Maybe it's related to drivers somehow. I had some issues with drivers on Win8 too.

Comment: @Shyju Please provide more information about the configuration of your wireless network. I am interested in what mode and band its running on. Mode: 802.11N, 802.11G, ect Band: 2.4GHz or 5.0GHz

Comment: @Ramhound: Please see the edit. I added WIFI Settings.

Comment: Are you using a 802.11N or 802.11G adapter

Comment: @Ramhound Where do i check that ?

Comment: @Shyju - Product specifications for the adapter your using of course.